# Setting up Wordpress on MAMP PRO. admin blank page

Tags: wordpress, mamp-pro

I have set up my MAMP PRO and a virtual host named YDF at which I have Installed the complement of Word Press 4.
![enter image description here][1]

When I do enter in the Manage my admin user & password it redirects me to  http://ydf/wp-login.php where it indicates that this webpage is not available.
* the folder YDF is within htdocs folder that is my root folder.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion is to make sure your WordPress installation is set up correctly. The database should be created and its credentials entered into wp-config.php. Just copy wp-config-sample.php and follow the inline comments.

My second suggestion is to make sure MAMP is setup correctly. Usually the url should have some kind of domain (ydf.dev or ydf.local for example).

MAMP also uses port 8080 by default, so your site might be at ydf:8080

Hope that helps

Comment: Could you share what the solution was for others who might run into the same problem?